# ¿Cómo colocar un resultado en cierta fila de una tabla con jquery?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

multiplico el precio por el numero de pedido, en la primera fila si se hace bien la multiplicacion, pero en la segunda fila cuando hago la multiplicacion me tomo el valor del input number de la primera fila y el resultado tambien me lo arrojo en la primera fila. estoy usando jquery y jsp.

Los datos los cargo de una base de datos.

No encuntro como hacer que funcione como debe.

asi es como tengo la tabla.

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="dynamic-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                                    <thead>

                                                                                    <th>Idproducto</th>
       <th>Nombre</th>
       <th>Descripcion</th>
        <th>Categoria</th>    
        <th>Precio</th>  
        <th>Pedido</th>  
         <th>Total</th>  
          <th>Salvar</th>  

                                                        </thead>
 <jsp:useBean id="cn1" class="dao.actualizarregistro" scope="page"></jsp:useBean>
                <%ResultSet rs1= cn1.mostrar();

               %>

               <%while(rs1.next()){


                  %>
        <tbody>
                  <tr class="t">

            <td class="p" ><%=rs1.getInt(1)%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString(2)%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getString(3)%></td>
             <td><%=rs1.getString(4)%></td>
            <td class="boton"><%=rs1.getString(5)%></td>
            <td><input id="coins" type="number" name="coins" value="1" max="999" min="1"> </td>
            <td> <b id="numero"></b></td>
            <td width='20px;'><a class='l1s' title='Eliminar de lista de ventas'><img src='mr.jpeg' /></a>

            </td>

        </tr>
         </tbody>
        <% }%>


    </table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cualquier pregunta del tipo "_en HTML/JavaScript funciona para el primero, pero no para los demás_", la respuesta generalmente es: **tienes IDs duplicados**.

Comment: Hola david, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] y que leas [ask] para ver cómo funciona el sitio y obtener información sobre cómo mejorar tus publicaciones. Por ejemplo, parece que el problema que tienes es al actualizar unos números dinámicamente con JavaScript, pero el código que compartes no tiene nada de JavaScript.